# android if-else statement not executing expectedly

Tags: android

Hi I am building a calculator with a TextView that responds to button presses.
The TextView starts off blank and when I press a math sign it works correctly by not showing. However clicking more than once ignores the condition from the if-else statement and prints a sign. I know I'm missing something basic. Here is a portion of the code.

```
//Answer Space assignment
        final TextView input = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerSpace);
        input.setText("");


 //CLEAR
        Button clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        input.setText("");

                    }
                }
        );

        //PLUS
        final Button plusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
        plusButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                     if(input.getText().equals(""))
                     {
                         input.append("");
                     }
                        else
                     {
                         input.append("+");

                     }
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: you want to say that if textview is blank and if u press plus button more than once it gets appended to textview . is it so ? @gwolf07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      public void onClick(View v){
                 if(input.getText().trim().length > 0)
                 {
                     input.append("+");
                 }
                }
```

This will avoid adding + sign if textview have whitespace

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Makes more sense logically.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace this

public void onClick(View v)
{
   if(input.getText().equals(""))
   {
       input.append("");
   }
   else
   {
       input.append("+");
   }
}

with this

public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(!input.getText().equals(""))
    {
         input.append("+");
    }
}
```